# One-to-one correspondence with uncountable set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have $P$, an uncountable set, and $Q$, a countably infinite subset of $P$. My textbook claims, without further comment, that $P$ can be put in a one-to-one correspondence with $P\setminus Q$. Why is this the case? Can anyone help me construct a more elaborate proof, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It might be helpful to think about contradiction.

Say $Q$ and $Q^c$ *both* have cardinality strictly less than $P$. What would the cardinality of $Q \cup Q^c$ be? Notice $Q \cup Q^c = P$... Do you see how to use this to get a contradiction?

---

I hope this helps ^_^